# Restrict movement of UIButton along a UIBezierPath path

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I have a circular `UIBezierPath`. I use the path to draw a circle on my view to create an outline of a 24 hr clock. I have a UIButton whose position depends on the current time. The button acts like an Hour hand. I want the users to be able to move the UIButton along the circular path. I call it "visit the future/past" feature. How do I restrict the buttons movement to the path I have?

Comment: Is the button supposed to respond to linear gestures?

Comment: Currently I am using `UILongGestureRecognizer`

Comment: That is to detect long press which I am guessing you will use to start the drag operation. How is the button supposed to behave if the user now drags the button along a straight line?

Comment: I suppose I record the initial point and get the difference in x and y from initial and current point and then use the difference to identify where the button should be. It is kind of hard to drag a button in an absolute straight line but if that happens, the button stays in its initial position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `touchesBegan:` and `touchesMoved:` methods in your view

```
- (void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
   if([[event touchesForView:button] count])
   {
       //User is trying to move the button set a variable to indicate this.
   }
}



- (void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint *point = [[event anyObject] locationInView:self];

    /*Compare x and y coordinates with the centre property of the button 
      If x or y are greater set center of button to next point in circle or previous
      point if any of them are lesser.*/
}
```

Note that you will have to save all points in your circle in an array before attempting this or you will have to calculate the points on the circumference of the circle by knowing the radius.

Comment: Do i need the first method? I already have the initial point when I set the button's position according to time. And I would rather calculate the point but how would I? I have the radius but would'nt I need an angle with respect to the center point?

Comment: Since you are overriding touches moved on the view it will be called for all touches, the 1st method is required to let you know that the user in fact started by touching the button

Comment: Even if you calculate the angle you would finally have to convert that to points on circumference. It would serve you better to directly use the points instead.

Comment: I will try both these approaches + the one below and get back to you. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: So I have a new [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562372/more-precise-cgpoint-for-uilongpressgesturerecognizer), if you could look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is in touchesMoved, you can check to ignore touch which is not in your circle view by using:

```
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:circleView];

if (![circleView pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
     return;
}
```

Comment: I will look at `pointInside: withEvent:` and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: I have a custom UIView. In this view's drawRect, I draw the circle. If I then use `pointInside: withEvent:`, will it work? The circle is not a stand alone uiview, it's drawn on a view.

Comment: In case it is not a stand alone view then I assume that you place your circle in the middle of screen, so center point of screen is match to center point of circle, you can calculate to get the distance from touch point to center point of circle then compare it to radius of circle.